# Stripe Charges vs Orders clarifications

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm implementing a payment platform with Stripe.
For a single payment I create a Charge.
It works, no problem, but I also need to apply a tax fee to the product which is defined in the Order object.
Does that mean I need to replace Charges with Orders somehow or is Order a parent object for the charge? If so how do I link those 2 together? Or there is a way to apply tax fees to charges I didn't see?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
    public async Task<StripeCharge> CreateStripeChargeAsync(StripeProduct product, StripeSku sku, StripeCustomer customer, string orderId)
    {
        var charge = await _chargeService.CreateAsync(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = sku.Price,
            Currency = sku.Currency,
            Description = product.Description,
            CustomerId = customer.Id,
            SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = customer.DefaultSourceId,
            ReceiptEmail = customer.Email,
            Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "OrderId", orderId }
            }
        });

        return charge;
    }
```

Comment: Have you even looked at the API docs? https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#order_object

Comment: yes and I'm not sure what I need to use which is why I humbly ask the question. Thanks for the useful comment

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tax to your order by creating an order item with the type set to tax, for example

```
Stripe\OrderItem JSON: {
    "object": "order_item",
    "type": "tax",
    "amount": 1234,
    "currency": "usd",
    "description": "Tax",
    "parent": "null",
    "quantity": null
}
```

Attach this to your orders item list. I can't really give a code example since you didn't mention a language but your order object would look like...

```
Stripe\Order JSON: {
"id": "or_1CZfbeCAQSQw5dVw1BSP63dZ",
"object": "order",
"amount": 1500,
"amount_returned": null,
"application": null,
"application_fee": null,
"charge": null,
"created": 1528206830,
"currency": "usd",
"customer": null,
"email": null,
"items": [
  {
    "object": "order_item",
    "amount": 10000,
    "currency": "usd",
    "description": "My Product name",
    "parent": "sk_1BQuNoCAQSQw5dVwjf30OpxH",
    "quantity": null,
    "type": "sku"
  },
    "object": "order_item",
    "type": "tax",
    "amount": 1234,
    "currency": "usd",
    "description": "Tax",
    "parent": "null",
    "quantity": null
], etc...
```

You can use the same idea for adding shipping costs or even applying discounts by using type="shipping" or "discount".

Notice the order object contains a charge field. Once the order is paid this is populated with the charge id. No need to replace charges with orders, Stripe will do this update for you linking the payment to the order.

See the [API Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#orders) for more information.

Comment: The question wasn't language oriented but I added the code. So the user select a product in our website, which creates a charge atm, I just need to add taxes for this. You're basically saying I shouldn't use the charge object to do that but the order object to be able to add the tax fees?

Comment: the orderid in my code is just the id of a document in my db where a copy of the charge + some other infos are saved, it's not the StripeOrder object

Comment: When the user clicks "buy" you should create an order object. Then call `Order.pay();` which creates the charge.

Comment: Oh the order creates the charge? So I'm not supposed to create the charge manually as I did?

Comment: but I can for example set ReceiptEmail which will send the receipt and other behaviours on charges, I don't see an equivalent in orders

Comment: It's a bit strange how everyone talks about charges if order should be used instead letting it take care of the charge ..

Comment: The order object has an email property but you shouldn't need it as the email comes from the customer object. order->email just overrides the customer email. Your pulling the email from customer already so it should work by default.

Comment: Many routes to get to a charge, via subscriptions, invoices, orders etc. Pick the right one for the situation. I see a charge as being the end result of some other process.

Comment: Alright I guess I should't have gone for the charge directly I'll need to test that a bit, thanks

Comment: can you put that in your original post so I can flag it answered?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, adding a item of type tax. Can't do at creation it says...